# How to count adjacent recurring elements in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, counter

I have an array of 0's and 1's as such

```
[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]
```

I want to define a function that will take this array as input and output an array of the same length, with the count of adjacent 1's in the index where the first 1 appeared (and 0 otherwise). So the output would be

```
[0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0]
```

because 1 appeared in the 2nd index 3 consecutive times and 1 appeared in the 9th index 2 consecutive times.

Is there a way to do this using numpy? If not, is there some (efficient) pythonic way to do it?

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Since it's not clear what you have tried, perhaps look into [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)?

Comment: What is the output for a non-adjacent '1', e.g. `[0, 1, 0]`?  is it `[0, 0, 0]` or `[0, 1, 0]`?  Your explanation implies the former, but only indirectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using pure vectorized operations and no list iterations:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0])
output = np.zeros_like(data)

where = np.where(np.diff(data))[0]
vals = where[1::2] - where[::2]
idx = where[::2] + 1

output[idx] = vals
output
# array([0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Note that this fails if `data` ends with a 1.

Comment: It also fails if `data` begins with `1`. I think it works if `data[0]` and `data[-1]` are the same

Answer (score 2):

Using the `itertools` module:

```
from itertools import chain, groupby

A = [0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]

def get_lst(x):
    values = list(x[1])
    return [len(values)] + [0]*(len(values) - 1) if x[0] else values

res = list(chain.from_iterable(map(get_lst, groupby(A))))

# [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Considering that OP has used `numpy` and that there are also many similar and better generator/itertools answers here this one is very inefficient. If you want to use `itertools` or in general Python, there are already better and faster ways to do this.

Comment: @Kasrâmvd, Completely agree. I'd advise OP to choose a NumPy alternative should one be offered.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the consecutive elements:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]


def groups(lst):
    result = []
    for key, group in groupby(lst):
        if not key:  # is a group of zeroes
            result.extend(list(group))
        else:  # is a group of ones
            count = sum(1 for _ in group)
            if count > 1:  # if more than one
                result.append(count)
                result.extend(0 for _ in range(count - 1))
            else:
                result.append(0)
    return result


print(groups(a))
```

**Output**

```
[0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

A shorter (more *pythonic*?) is the following:

```
def groups(lst):
    for key, group in groupby(lst):
        count = sum(1 for _ in group)
        if key and count > 1:
            yield count
        yield from (0 for _ in range(count - key))


print(list(groups(a)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using numpy and a list comprehension:

```
In [23]: a = np.array([0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0])
In [24]: np.hstack([x.sum() if x[0] == 1 else x for x in np.split(a, np.where(np.diff(a) != 0)[0]+1)])
Out[24]: array([0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0])
```

The logic:

1. Find leading and trailing indices of where you have consequence 1s.
2. Split your array from those indices
3. sum those sub lists that have one and  leave sub lists with zero the way they are
4. flatten the result using `np.hstack`.

If you want to replace the remained ones with 0 just do the following:

```
In [28]: np.hstack([[x.sum(), *[0]*(len(x) -1)]  if x[0] == 1 else x for x in np.split(a, np.where(np.diff(a) != 0)[0]+1)])
Out[28]: array([0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0])
```

`[0]*(len(x) -1)` will create the expected 0s for you and using an in-place unpacking you'll be able to place them beside the `sum(x)`.

If you ever wanted a pure Python approach here's one way using `itertools.groupby`:

```
In [63]: def summ_cons(li):
    ...:     for k,g in groupby(li) :
    ...:            if k:
    ...:               s = sum(g)
    ...:               yield s
    ...:               yield from (0 for _ in range(s-1))
    ...:            yield from g
    ...:            


In [65]: list(summ_cons(a))
Out[65]: [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: This produces an array that's shorter than the input array.

Comment: @fuglede Just added that case too

Comment: Your second example is perfect since it works for cases where the array start and end with 0 or 1... this is a great solution....  np.hstack([[x.sum(), *[0]*(len(x) -1)]  if x[0] == 1 else x for x in np.split(a, np.where(np.diff(a) != 0)[0]+1)])

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas, take advantage in pandas `count` counts non-NaN values.  Create NaNs using `mask` then groupby changes in values of s.

```
import pandas as pd
l = [0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]
s = pd.Series(l)
g = s.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
s.mask(s==0).groupby(g).transform('count').mask(g.duplicated(), 0).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

using [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby
a=[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]
lst_of_tuples=[]
for k,v in groupby(a):
    lst_of_tuples.append((k,len(list(v))))
ans=[]
for k,v in lst_of_tuples:
    temp=[v if k==1 else k]
    for i in range(v-1):
        temp.append(0)
    ans=ans+temp
```

output

```
[0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0]
```

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR: this gives you the output you want:

```
import itertools

input = [0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]   
result = []

for k, g in itertools.groupby(input):
    if k == 1:
        ll = len(list(g))
        result.extend([ll,] + [0 for _ in range(ll-1)])
    else:
        result.extend(list(g))
```

will give you:

```
[0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

## explanation:

itertools has the `groupby` function to split runs of "the same"

```
for k, g in itertools.groupby(input):
    print(g, list(k))
```

will give you:

```
0 [0, 0]
1 [1, 1, 1]
0 [0, 0, 0, 0]
1 [1, 1]
0 [0, 0]
```

so `k` is the key, the element in the input sequence and `g` is the group.

so the if conditions appends either (in case of a 0) the series of 0's from the input, or the length if the run of 1's plus zeros to fill up for the length of the 1-run.

Comment: The output array length does not match the input array length.

Answer (score 0):

**Other option with no dependencies:**

The good old `while` loop accessing by index (sometimes faster than numpy):

```
def count_same_adjacent_non_zeros(iterable):
  i, x, size = 0, 0, len(iterable)
  while i < size-1:
    if iterable[i] != iterable[i+1]:
      tmp = iterable[x:i+1]
      if not iterable[i] == 0:
        tmp = [len(tmp)] + [0 for _ in range(i-x)]
      for e in tmp: yield e
      x = i + 1
    i += 1
  for e in iterable[x:size]: yield e


print(list(count_same_adjacent_non_zeros(array)))

#=> [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

It works also with `array = [0,0,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,5,5,0,0]`